# Error : Unknown Table in the field list

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MAPPING_TABLE_TEMP
(
T_TABLENAME VARCHAR(50), 
T_COLUMNNAME VARCHAR(50), 
S_TABLENAME VARCHAR(50), 
S_COLUMNNAME VARCHAR(4000), 
VERSION_NUMBER INT,
CONSTRAINT_TYPE VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO MAPPING_TABLE_TEMP (SELECT T_TABLENAME,T_COLUMNNAME,S_TABLENAME,S_COLUMNNAME,VERSION_NUMBER,CONSTRAINT_TYPE FROM mapping_table);
-- 
get_constraintType : LOOP

IF(MAPPING_TABLE_TEMP.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='PK') THEN

    INSERT INTO RULEMAPPING(RULEID,T_TABLENAME,T_COLUMNNAME,S_TABLENAME,S_COLUMNNAME,EXECUTION_FLAG,SAMPLING_PERCENTAGE,RMID,LAST_EXECUTION_DATE,VERSION_NUMBER)
    VALUES(
    '2',T_TABLENAME,T_COLUMNNAME,S_TABLENAME,S_COLUMNNAME,'',100,'1',CURDATE(),VERSION_NUMBER);

END IF;

END LOOP;
```

If i change MAPPING_TABLE_TEMP to NEW in the if condition, it 'll say Unknown table 'NEW', if i remove new also, then it is giving unknown column 'CONSTRAINT_TYPE'.

Please help .

Comment: mysql error code returned?

Comment: "NEW" is used in triggers.  Is there a trigger body somewhere?

Comment: @Packet: There is no error code..@Gordon..No..i havent used any trigger .

Comment: Can anybody tell me where is the mistake?